# give the input format when converting a date

Tags: linux, date, format

I read the date from a file to a variable. The date has the format ddmmyyyy. It has to be converted to yyyy-mm-dd
I already searched this forum and got this far :
date -d '$DATE' +%F
The problem is the input format is not recognised. Is there any way I can specify the input date format?
On an other forum I found : date -d "${OLD_DATE}" -D "%d%m%Y" +%F 
where -D should specify the input format but this doesn't work. But -D is unknown.

thanks for the help and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to it like this:

```
echo "DDMMYYYY" | awk 'BEGIN {OFS="-"} {print substr($1,5,4), substr($1,3,2), substr($1,1,2)}'
```

Output:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: Well, if my answer was helpful, you could upvote /accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `date` understands a lot of formats for `-d`, but when it's just 8 digits in a row, it interprets it as `YYYYmmdd`. I'm not sure if you can force it to read it differently, but in this case you can use a simple editor such as `awk` or `sed` instead:

```
$ OLD_DATE='08032011'
$ echo $OLD_DATE | sed -r 's/(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})/\3-\2-\1/'
2011-03-08
```

This will work on `GNU sed`. Note that it doesn't check the input (for brevity).